# Bluemix Auto Scaling API

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is there a way for me to programmatically get notified when Bluemix auto scaling has scaled up or down?

I'm reading streaming data from a queue and would like to make sure the number of instances that I have are balanced and data is partitioned correctly

Answer (score 0):

At present this kind of notification service is not available, only you can do is query the instance scaling history in Web UI. I think this requirement is interesting and should be considered to provide to developer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of alert isn't available yet but you can write a simple script monitoring output of

cf app (appname)

It returns the number of instances running and the state of each one, with the right combination of awk and grep (or a perl script for example) you could have your own alerter while waiting for this of functionality